# Faddeev-Kulish Asymptotic Dynamics Question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, research-level

I am reading a paper by Faddeev and Kulish (["Asymptotic conditions and infrared divergences in QED"](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01066485) written in 1970) and I have a question regarding the nonrelativistic problem of Coulomb scattering. The authors claim that in the nonrelativistic Coulomb scattering, the potential can be expanded in powers of the $t$, where $t$ is the time which is present in the Coulomb potential through the substitution of the distance $r$ between the scattering particle and the scatterer, which is given by
$$\hat{r}(t)=\frac{\hat{p}}{m}+\hat{r},$$
where $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{p}$ are time independent operators in QM. The expansion goes as follows
$$V(t)=\frac{mg}{pt}+\mathcal{O}(t^{-2})$$
where $g$ is the product of the charges of the scattering particle and the scatterer. Then, they solve the Schroedinger equation for the asymptotic regions in space, in which the Hamiltonian is comprised by the kinetic term and the first term in the expansion of $V(t)$, rather than the kinetic term alone. The wave function is given by
$$\psi(\vec{r},t)=\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}c(\vec{p})\exp\bigg(-i\frac{p^2}{2m}-i\frac{mg}{p}\text{sign}t\ln{\frac{|t|}{t_0}}\bigg)e^{i\vec{p}\cdot{\vec{r}}}$$
which, indeed, solves the differential equation. However, upon trying to derive an expression for the mean value $<\hat{r}(t)>$, then with the method of stationary phase, one recovers
$$<\hat{r}(t)>=\frac{<\hat{p}>}{m}t-gm<\frac{\hat{p}}{p^2}>\text{sign}t\ln{|t|}+\mathcal{O}(1)$$
Doesn't the last expression contradict the initial assumption that
$$\hat{r}(t)=\frac{\hat{p}}{m}+\hat{r}~ ?$$

Comment: what's the meaning of $\hat{r}(t)=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+\hat{r}$?

Comment: It is a typo. Sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in you taking $\hat{r}(t) = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2 m} + \hat{r}$, whereas it should be $\hat{r}(t) = \frac{\hat{p}}{m} t + \hat{r}$. The calculation checks out when the latter is chosen.

Comment: Hi Karen. Excuse my typo please. I have fixed that now. What I meant by the question is the following: it seems to me that we start with a pair of initial conditions for $\hat{r}$ and for $\hat{p}$ and then when we try to calculate the expectation values for those operators, then the former does not match the initial condition, since its second term involves a logarithmically diverging time dependent term

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question. First of all, there is still a typo in your question: you write
$\hat{\vec{r}}(t) = \frac{\hat{\vec{p}}}{2 m} + \hat{\vec{r}}$,
but it should be
$\hat{\vec{r}}(t) = \frac{\hat{\vec{p}}}{m} t + \hat{\vec{r}}$.

Comment: Assuming that was just a typo, I see two possible sources of misunderstanding:

(1) Attempting to take $t \to 0$ in the expression for $\langle \hat{\vec{r}}(t) \rangle$. This expression is true exclusively in the $|t| \to \infty$ limit; it falls apart for small $|t|$'s.

Comment: (2) Not realizing that
$$\langle \psi_I (t) | \hat{\vec{r}} | \psi_I(t) \rangle = - g m \left\langle \frac{\hat{\vec{p}}}{\hat{\vec{p}}^2} \right\rangle \mathrm{sign}(t) \ln |t|$$
where $| \psi_I(t) \rangle$ is the interaction-picture state, namely,
$$| \psi_I(t) \rangle  = e^{i t H_0} | \psi(t) \rangle$$
where $| \psi(t) \rangle$ is the state in Eq. (2) of the article.

Comment: Hi Karen! Sorry again for leaving typos in my question! I think I have fixed them now. So if I get it correctly, you suggest that in the equation $\hat{\vec{r}}(t)=\frac{\hat{\vec{p}}}{m}t+\hat{\vec{r}}$, the "time-independent" $\hat{\vec{r}}$ has an expectation value in the interaction picture that is proportional to the logarithm of $t$?? And if so, why is that??

Comment: Exactly. That pretty much straightforwardly follows from the expression for the state [Eq. (2) in the paper]:
$$\psi_I(q, t) := \langle q | \psi_I(t) \rangle = \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2 \pi)^3} c(\vec{p}) \exp\left[ i \vec{p} \vec{r} - i \frac{m g}{| \vec{p}|} \mathrm{sign}(t) \ln \frac{t}{t_0} \right].$$
Just calculating $\langle \psi_I(t) | \vec{r} | \psi_I(t) \rangle$ using this expression gives the answer. The only seminontrivial step in calculating this is realizing that
$$\int \frac{d^3 \vec{r}}{(2 \pi)^3} \vec{r} e^{\vec{r} \vec{p}} = \mathrm{grad}_{\vec{p}} \delta (\vec{p}).$$

Comment: Thank you so much Karen. I think I am getting it, but still not entirely there. Could you please clarify one last thing? So, the way I see it, there is a contradiction, even if I can do the derivation you are suggesting: we assumed that in the $|t|\rightarrow\infty$ limit, the trajectory of the non-relativistic particle is one such that $\hat{\vec{r}}=\frac{\hat{\vec{p}}}{m}+{\hat{\vec{r}}}$(i.e. the second term is constant in time). Despite the fact that this was our original assumption, the derivations lead us to an expectation value, whose second term is logarithmically time dependent.

Comment: How would you explain that?? In both cases we are at the $|t|\rightarrow$ limit, so I would exlude this from the explanation I think. Is it the fact that in the one case we have expectation values, whereas in the other we have just the operators? But again, shouldn't the expectation values resemble the classical limit in some sense? Or is it because we are in the interaction picture while calculating the expectation values?? But on the other hand, expectation values should be picture independent right?

Comment: Absolutely! The expectation value does not depend on the picture:
$$\langle \psi_I(t)| \hat{\vec{r}}(t) |\psi_I(t) \rangle = \langle \psi(t)| \hat{\vec{r}} |\psi(t) \rangle .$$

It is also true that the discrepancy you perceive relates to the fact that one object is an operator, and the one is an average.

Comment: The operator $\hat{\vec{r}}$ is spread all over the space:
$$\hat{\vec{r}}=\int d^3\vec{r}\,\vec{r}|\vec{r}\rangle\langle\vec{r}|.$$
So what happens is that initially the state is localized around some $\vec{r}_0$, so that the expectation value of $\hat{\vec{r}}$ is close to $\vec{r}_0$. Then, in the course of the evolution, the state spreads out in a way that the expectation value of $\hat{\vec{r}}$ becomes the weird function of $t$ that it is (speaking of the specific case considered by Faddeev and Kulish).

Comment: Thank you Karen, thank you so much